# Show message for empty form field?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the optin form on my website to not send empty fields.

I also have predefined text within the form fields (Ex. "Enter you name here" ) that disappears on click.  I don't want the form to send predefined text data either.

What is the best way to go about this with PHP?

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
<h2>Get An Appointment: <font size="3"><font color="#6E5769">Fill in the form below now, and I'll call you to setup your next dental appointment...</font></font></h2>
<p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
<form action="contact.php" method="post"/>
<p class="name">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="text-align:center;" onClick="this.value='';" value="Enter your name"/>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$to = 'test@mywebsite.com'; $subject = 'New Patient';

$name = $_POST['name']; $phone = $_POST['phone'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hi, my name is $name, and phone number is $phone.

EMAIL;

$header = 'From: test@mywebsite.com';

if($_POST){ if($name != '' && $phone != ''){ mail($to, $subject, $body, $header); }else{ $feedback = 'Fill out all the fields'; } } ?>
```

Comment: A problem is that you use OR in: if($name == '' || $phone == '') this means that OR name OR phone with some test will result in mailing the email. I think an && will work better. Like the examples just posted.

Comment: Hello...if you have something new to add to a question then please edit the original, don't post a new question. I've merged your new question with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all information in `POST` array and then remove the empty values using `array_filter`

Added an sample http://codepad.org/ZtR6Eh93

Answer (score 0):

Heres try this:

```
<?php
$to = 'test@mywebsite.com';
$subject = 'New Patient';

$header = 'From: test@mywebsite.com';

$feedback = null;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $name = (!empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:null);
    $phone = (!empty($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:null);

    $body = <<<EMAIL
Hi, my name is $name, and phone number is $phone.
EMAIL;

    if($name !== null && $phone !== null){
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
        $feedback = 'Message Sent';
    }else{
        $feedback = 'Fill out all the fields';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first you should do validation on **client-side** using JavaScript.

```
<? 

$name = $phone = $status= '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = (!empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:null);
    $phone = (!empty($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:null);

    if($name !== null && $phone !== null){
       mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
       $name = $phone = '';
       $status = 'Message Sent';
    }
    else
       $status= 'Fill out all the fields';

}      

<? if(!empty($status)): ?><p class="error"><?=$status?></p><? endif; ?>

<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name?>"/>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?=$phone?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use empty() on the $_POST variables, preferably on the required form field (Not just $_POST). For example:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
  // Name field was posted
}
```

This is different to isset because isset will return true if the field was something like "" or NULL. Whereas !empty only accepts values that are not empty / not null. Hence why the empty function is a better choice in this case.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by checking in the server side:

```
if($_POST){ if($name != '' && $phone != '' && $name!='Enter your name' && $email!='Enter your email'){ mail($to, $subject, $body, $header); }else{ $feedback = 'Fill out all the fields'; } } ?>
```

But I suggest that you improve your error handling to something like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $err = array();
    if ($name == '' || $name == 'Enter your name') $err[] = 'Name is required';
    if ($email == '' || $email == 'Enter your email') $err[] = 'Email is required';
    if (empty($err)) {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    } else {
        $feedback = 'Fill out all fields. Errors: '.implode(', ',$err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean `if (empty($err)) { ...` instead, otherwise that if will always evaluate to false

Answer (score 0):

Add onsubmit handler to your form that set `disabled` property to `true` for all inputs which you don't like to be sent

**Update:**

This does not relax the requirement to check all input parameters at PHP side of your app.